# Wordpress php shortcode inside a php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello and thank you very much for your help.
Im trying to personalize a theme in Wordpress but i'm having problems with PHP.

My problem is.. i have 2 php codes and i need to intregate both and i don't know how.

First code (working):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[products skus="XXX" orderby="date" order="desc"]' ); ?>
```

Second code: (working):

```
<?php $key="_vb_artist_sku"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>
```

My problem is i need to replace the "XXX" from the first code with de result of the second code.
i try something like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[products skus="<?php $key="_vb_artist_sku"; echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true); ?>" orderby="date" order="desc"]' ); ?>
```

but does not work.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Your trying to make a declaration(`$key="_vb_artist_sku";`) in a echo statement? That won't work! Also never have 2x php tags(`<?php` `?>`) inside the other!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $key = "_vb_artist_sku";
    $sku = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, true);
    echo do_shortcode('[products skus="'.$sku.'" orderby="date" order="desc"]');
?>
```

I've used the [string concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/it/language.operators.string.php) `.` to alter the string before passing it to `do_shortcode`.

Comment: That works =), thank you very much for your time, example and help!

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
echo do_shortcode( sprintf( '[products skus="%s" orderby="date" order="desc"]', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_vb_artist_sku', true ) ) );
```